# Find Last Non-zero (+Non-blank) Row Meeting Criteria in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, formula

I am trying to get the last non-zero, non-blank value of a row within a column (Column F in my example image) wherein that row ALSO matches a Campaign name (Column D).

Most search results yield an Excel-specific variation of `=LOOKUP(1,1/(L:L>0),L:L)`, but this doesn't work in Google Sheets.

I am trying to solve for **Cell F23 = 2374**.

I found and modified a formula which returns the last non-zero, non-blank value within a column reliably, but I don't know where to mix the additional filter (basically, `D$2:D22 = D23`) into the INDEX function.

Here is what I'm working with:

```
=if(

{{separate_formula_that_fetches_value_from_other_sheet}})=0, 

INDEX((FILTER(D$2:F22,NOT(ISBLANK(D$2:F22)))), (ROWS(FILTER(D$2:F22,NOT(ISBLANK(D$2:F22))))),3)

)
```

Here is the example table:

[image]

Thank you for any help!

Comment: don't really get what you are trying to accomplish... do you want to search for data inside B2:F22, which have Values in Column D equals to D23, and when there are more than 1 results, you only need the last one, and you need the result to be placed in F23?

Comment: @Ping I want to find the last non-zero, non-blank value in F$2:F22 where the D value for that value = D23. The value would come from F, and would be placed in F23.

Basically, yes to the scenario you layed out -- the data would only ever come from Column F, but column D is included in the index range because it's part of the filter criteria.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are trying to find inside RANGE B2:F22 which...

1. value in Column F is not empty and greater than 0, and
2. value in Column D matches D23,

try this, didn't test it, but it should work I think:

```
=LAMBDA(FILTER,
 INDEX(FILTER,COUNTA(FILTER))
)(FILTER($F$2:$F$22,$F$2:$F$22>0,$D$2:$D$22=$D23))
```

Comment: Well, it took some time to work it into the existing IF(), but this worked!! If you have any resources explaining what the heck the LAMBDA() function does, I'd love to learn.

Comment: official explaination for LAMBDA function: https://support.google.com/docs/answer/12508718?hl=en

Comment: in short, LAMBDA function, is a way to declare variables inside EXCEL or google sheet. So as to make the code more readable, and help a lot on shortening some repeating formulas.

Comment: you can indeed remove the LAMBDA function like this, the following formula is identical to the one in my answer: ```=INDEX(FILTER($F$2:$F$22,$F$2:$F$22>0,$D$2:$D$22=$D23),COUNTA(FILTER($F$2:$F$22,$F$2:$F$22>0,$D$2:$D$22=$D23))```

Comment: Without LAMBDA function, as you can see, it would be a pain in your axx if you need to make any changes in any of the range references.

Comment: But with LAMBDA function, you can change the formula to something like this: ```=LAMBDA(ColD,ColF,LookupValue,LAMBDA(FILTER,INDEX(FILTER,COUNTA(FILTER)))(FILTER(ColF,ColF>0,ColD=LookupValue)))($D$2:$D$22,$F$2:$F$22,$D23)```

Comment: As you can see, the core part ```FILTER(ColF,ColF>0,ColD=LookupValue))``` and ```INDEX(FILTER,COUNTA(FILTER))``` is very clear what we are doing, ```filter Column F, values in Column F needs to be > 0, and values in Column D must equal to LookupValue```, after that apply INDEX to result of the FILTER, return the value which have its index equal to COUNTA of the FILTER result, which in this case means the number of values found by the filter, which is equal to the row_num of last row of the given filter's result.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to explain.